# Comparing structure element to int

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
    char nazwisko[30];
    double srednia;
    int semestr;
}osoba;

void WyszukiwanieSemestr(osoba *stud, int sem, int i)
{
    int a;
    printf("\n");
    for(a=0;a<i;++a)
    {
       if(stud[a].semestr == sem)
       {
          printf("%d. %s %.3lf %d\n",a+1,stud[a].nazwisko,stud[a].srednia,stud[a].semestr);
       }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And in int main():

```
osoba *os;
os = (osoba*) malloc(M*sizeof(osoba));
int sem, i = 5;
scanf("%d",sem);
WyszukiwanieSemestr(os,sem,i);
```

When I try to compare stud[a].semestr == sem in the function, my program crashes.
What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: We need to see more code. `try.sem == i` is okay by itself.

Comment: probably due to an excessive strcpy into `x.naz`

Comment: What is M: is it 5?  Also, try printing the value of a inside the loop to tell you what value of a it is crashing at.

Comment: The biggest problem is the scanf.  I'm surprised this even compiles, but if it does, it will be using a random memory address to put the int into.  see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d",sem);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &sem);
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is likely your scanf.  You need to pass the ADDRESS of sem.  Instead, this is copying your keyboard input into a random memory location.

```
scanf("%d", &sem);
```

Also,

You're allocating M osoba objects for os, but you're passing in a size of 5 to WyszukiwanieSemestr.  You should pass in M instead.

If M is smaller than 5, you will run off the end of your array in your for loop inside WyszukiwanieSemestr

```
WyszukiwanieSemestr(os, sem, M);
```

Also, there's no need to cast the response from malloc.

Comment: I use #define M 15, so this shouldn't be the problem. :/