# Compare struct element to integer in c

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

I am working with linked lists. These are the structs I'm working with:

```
// List element: a list is a chain of these
typedef struct element
{
  int val;
  struct element* next;
} element_t;

// List header - keep track of the first and last list elements
typedef struct list
{
  element_t* head;
  element_t* tail;
} list_t;
```

I need to do something along the lines of this:

```
int i = 5;
if(*(list->tail) == i){
    //do something;
}
```

I know that `*(list->tail)` dereferences the pointer and returns the last element in the list, however I keep getting this error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('element_t' (aka 'struct element') and 'int')
                if(*(list->tail) != i){
```

I realize that comparing a struct to an int is invalid. My questions are:

1. Why does comparing the dereferenced pointer not work, even though `printf("%i",*(list->tail))` prints it out? Is this just the way 'C' works?
2. Is there a way around this?

I understand that this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764024/comparing-structure-element-to-int), but I don't quite understand how they are comparing the struct variable to the int. Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't you mean `list->tail->val`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing structure element to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764024/comparing-structure-element-to-int)

Comment: You are comparing apples with oranges, why you are directly comparing `list->tail`, which is pointer, with a specific value? maybe you want the value, `list->tail->val`

Comment: `if(*(list->tail) == i){` --> `if(list->tail && list->tail->val == i){`

Comment: The error message is very clear. If you don't understand the dup, you should consult a good C book about the basics.

Comment: @Jack yes this is what I was looking for

Comment: `printf("%i",*(list->tail))` is also not correct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('element_t' (aka 'struct element') and 'int')

This error means that you're trying to compare an `element_t` to an `int` and that doesn't make any sense because they aren't comparable to each other.

> Why does comparing the dereferenced pointer not work, even though `printf("%i",*(list->tail))` prints it out? Is this just the way 'C' works?

I don't think `printf("%i",*(list->tail))` should work because that would cast an `element_t` to an `int` and that wouldn't make sense. Either of these make sense.

- `printf("%i",list->tail->val);`
- `printf("%p",list->tail);`

> Is there a way around this?

Isn't this what you'd want?

```
list_t *list;

// ...

if(list->tail->val == i){
    //do something;
}
```

You get the list's `tail` and then you get the `tail`'s `val`.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Why does this work and the previous way not?

Comment: Like I said, @steal_1234: you're trying to compare things that can't be compared.